# How to kextunload in OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, kext

I'm starting to learn more about the mac os x internals. Now i want to load and unload some kernel extensions.

I startet to load the MS-DOS file system via

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/msdosfs.kext
```

I can check this by typing

```
kextstat | grep msdos
```

The command output shows the loaded kext-file.
But when i want to **unload** the MS-DOS file system:

```
sudo kextunload com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs
```

I get only this message:

```
Can't create com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs.
```

**What is wrong with the kextunload - line above?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[**`kextunload`**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/kextunload.8.html) can use the full Kernel Extension path, just like `kextload`.

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/msdosfs.kext
```

If you want to use the bundle identifier – the one listed by `kextstat` –, use the `-b` switch:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs
```

Comment: I get `Can't create –b.` if I use it... I'm on 10.8.3.

Comment: I know this is very old, but for reference if you get the "Can't create -b" it's because the hyphen is the wrong character, probably UTF-8 encoded dash or something copy and pasted from a website.  type the -b yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[kextload man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextload.8.html) can give you details. Here is the command I've been using:

```
sudo kextload /path/to/file.kext
```

OR [kextutil man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/kextutil.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/kextutil), this tool is useful for get some debug messages if there are errors in the loading process.

```
sudo kextutil /path/to/file.kext
```

And of course, the kextunload man page in the other answer. Here is the command I mainly use since I don't like to write out the entire bundle id:

```
sudo kextunload /path/to/file.kext
```

You can also use `kextstat` to verify if your kext file has been loaded:

```
kextstat | grep -v apple
```

This will list all third party kexts as long as 'apple' is not in the bundle id.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem (**Can't create –b. ; Can't create com.apple.driver.AppleUSBFTDI.**) trying "**sudo kextunload –b com.apple.driver.AppleUSBFTDI**" on os x 10.9.5

but after i used the full path (**sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBFTDI.kext/**), it worked...

*that only happens on some kexts*, for eg on other kext (/System/Library/Extensions/FTDIUSBSerialDriver.kext) , it works perfect with "**sudo kextunload -b com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver**"